# Bootstrap select dropdown to change search criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change multiple children drowdown by main dropdown.

The search criteria that gets changed is marked in red in the image below (which are also dropdowns, but are completely different search criteria based on the main dropdown selected)

How can I do so?

[image]

UPDATE:
I have some existing code, on select it is changing the text on what has been selected from a dropdown. Is there a way i can modify this code below?

```js
REAL.searchBy = function() {
          $('.search_by').find('select').change(function(){
             var search_by= $(this).val();
            $(this).parents('.search_by').find('.search_by_keyword').val('Enter '+(search_by));
          $(".search_by_keyword" ).attr('name',search_by.toLowerCase()).focus();
          })
 }
```

```html
<div class="search_by">
                                <div class="search-field">
                                    <label>Search By</label>

                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="search_by" style="display: none;">
                                        <option selected="">Search By</option>
                                        <option value="Id">Id</option>
                                        <option value="test">test</option>
                                        <option value="Pincode">Pincode</option>
                                    </select>
                             
                                </div>
                                <div class="search-field"><label>Keyword</label>
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter " class="form-control input-lg search_by_keyword" name="pincode">
                                </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Take a look jQuery event listeners and functions to modify DOM elements

Comment: Thanks @Valijon, I have tried this example http://jsfiddle.net/65Q9L/452/ however, when i apply the classes "form-control select picker" it breaks, im trying to apply it to this template http://preview.imithemes.com/real-spaces/index.html, it also needs to save the main dropdown state and children

Comment: can you show us your jQuery/JS code?

Comment: `jsFiddle` example is simple `select`, but in `imithemes.com` it is boostrap dropdown (`ul`)

Comment: sure, my search its the same as http://preview.imithemes.com/real-spaces/property-type.html search box, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach how to archive what you expect:

```js
$('.search_by').find('select').change(function(){
    var search_by= $(this).val();
    $(this).parents('.search_by').find('.search_by_keyword').val('Enter '+(search_by));
    $(".search_by_keyword" ).attr('name',search_by.toLowerCase()).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_by">
    <div class="search-field">
        <label>Search By</label>

        <select class="form-control selectpicker" name="search_by">
            <option selected="">Search By</option>
            <option value="Id">Id</option>
            <option value="test">test</option>
            <option value="Pincode">Pincode</option>
        </select>
                             
    </div>
    <div class="search-field">
        <label>Keyword</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter " class="form-control input-lg search_by_keyword" name="pincode">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, however i cannot get it to work with the existing code, even when I click on Cottage, it shows me the same options as the others and also cancels out the bootstrap styles

Comment: Can you see in debug console what error is throwing?

Comment: Gives no errors, any chance you can teamvier and view?

Comment: Try to put jQuery code inside `$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Here al jQuery code
});`

Comment: can you take a look at my edit please? the code and js you gave me keeps breaking the bootstrap elements, so would it be possible to edit the existing code that came in the template?

Comment: @Daniel. That what you expect? Now, when you choose an element, input text changes too...

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know what you mean? I was wondering if we could somehow modify these elements to get the result im requiring using all the existing code as adding query is breaking the bootstrap dropdown elements

Comment: Put it somewhere to able modify online

Comment: http://preview.imithemes.com/real-spaces-wp/ here it is online, its the first select option, modify using firebug? It is using jquery to do it